# Scala: Why does Array.ofDim[String](n) create an Array where values are initialized as nulls rather than empty strings?

Tags: scala, multidimensional-array, null

Since Scala advocates avoiding the usage of `null`, I do not understand why the default values are null in this specific use-case. Can someone please explain this ?

```
scala> Array.ofDim[String](1)
res0: Array[String] = Array(null)
```

On the other-hand, defaults for other types seems to be fine.

```
scala> Array.ofDim[Double](1)
res1: Array[Double] = Array(0.0)

scala> Array.ofDim[Int](1)
res2: Array[Int] = Array(0)

scala> Array.ofDim[Boolean](1)
res3: Array[Boolean] = Array(false)

scala> Array.ofDim[Float](1)
res4: Array[Float] = Array(0.0)
```

UPDATE/EDIT:
Not that it is a big deal, I can map over the array and wrapping each element in Option and fold it by providing default value is "". I want to understand why this is the default behavior

Comment: Use `Array.fill` or `Array.tabulate`.

Comment: I think this is the only reasonable default. This is consistent with the Variable Declarations and Definitions (http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#variable-declarations-and-definitions) of Scala language specification.
Anyway indeed `null` values are discouraged, because the optionality can be expressed in the type system, and not by using special values (empty string would be just another 'special value'). And foremost empty strings would be super bad idea, as I bet it would lead to tons of bugs

Answer (score 2):

`ofDim` can be used to create/provide an array, when you have to call a Java API for example which expects nulls.

Another use case might be performance, when every instance counts, since arrays are the only collection which is supported directly by the JVM.

If you want an initialized array, you can use `fill`:

```
val sa = Array.fill(5)("Hi")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you declared an array of `String`s. And a `String`'s default value is `null`. (Remember that this `String` is a `java.lang.String`, whose default is null.)